# Accidentally decreased the size of everything in visual studio code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I was programming a discord bot and I accidentally hit a few buttons and everything in visual studio code just shrank. Text, buttons, icons, the windows inside vs code, everything

Everything is still visible of course but I want to revert it back to its original size. Can anyone help me?

Edit: I got help and it worked. If you have the same issue try `Ctrl` + `+`

Comment: Maybe `Ctrl + +` can help

Comment: Please don't put solutions in a question as an edit. If you've solved your problem, it belongs in an answer.

Answer (score 4):

try ctrl + mousewheel to adjust the size again.

or ctrl + (+ to increase or - to decrease the size)

Comment: didnt work but i used another method and it did (Ctrl + +)

Comment: Added your answer to my answer so people can benefit.